# NextJS serve static file as application/json

Tags: json, next.js

I have a webapp developped in NextJS with the domain `quinck.io` ( https://www.quinck.io/ ).

I have the need to serve a static JSON file from the path `quinck.io/apple-app-site-association` with the header `Content-Type: application/json`.

Right now I've inserted the file `apple-app-site-association`, which is a JSON file without the `.json` ( it is a requirement from Apple ), right now Chrome will download the file since it's not served as `application/json` ( try it from https://quinck.io/apple-app-site-association )

It is possible to achieve the same returning the JSON content ( example: https://reddit.com/apple-app-site-association )

What I've tried:

Custom headers for that path but it still being served as `application/octet-stream`

```
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/apple-app-site-association',
        locale: false,
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Content-Type',
            value: 'application/json',
          }
        ],
      },
    ]
  }
```

Rerouting to custom API endpoint returning JSON response

```
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/apple-app-site-association',
        destination: '/api/apple-app-site-association'
      }

    ]
  }
```

None of this above solution did work.

Comment: Same exact use case here, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
  async rewrites() {
   return [
    {
      source: '/apple-app-site-association',
      destination: '/api/apple-app-site-association'
  }]
```

This is the correct solution.
It didn't work before because I had the file `apple-app-site-association`inside the `public` folder.

Right now it only works locally, cannot fully understand why. When I upload it on Amplify it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Try configuring the rewrite in AWS Amplify instead. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html.